# Leer código de barras, pasar a TextBox y ejecutar consulta

Tags: c#, eventos, código-de-barras

Tengo una aplicación en C# donde escaneo un código de barras y me busca información en la base de datos. Lo que quiero saber es cómo buscar esa información de una forma automática, que cuando yo escanee el número me busque la información sin tener que presionar ningún botón.

Sólo quiero que alguien me guie en cómo hacerlo pues aun no tengo código.

Comment: ¿Cómo haces el escaneo, es un QR, un código de barras, desde teclado?

Comment: Sin código, es muy fácil malinterpretar lo que pides.

Comment: Es un code-128.

Comment: Los lectores de código de barras en general son por asi decirlo basicamente un teclado. Lo que debes hacer es asegurarte de que está el `TextBox` seleccionado y como te contestó gbianchi, suscribirte al evento `TextChanged` del `TextBox`,esperar a que el texto introducido tenga el tamaño adecuado, y en ese momento lanzar la busqueda del codigo.

Comment: como hago para que no se ejecute hasta que este todo el codigo escaneado?

Answer (score 4):

Lo primero que tienes que saber sobre los [códigos-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128)(información en inglés) es el formato que tienen (o el que deberían tener) incluye lo siguiente:

- A la izquierda, una zona en blanco que debería tener la longitud de dos caracteres.
- El carácter de inicio.
- Un número variable de caracteres ASCII y es lo más útil de este código.
- Un dígito para checkear la integridad de los datos.
- Un carácter de fin o "Stop character"
- A la derecha, una zona en blanco equivalente a dos caracteres.

Aquí te dejo las parte de una manera más gráfica

1. Zona en blanco
2. Carácter de inicio
3. Los datos codificados
4. Carácter de verificación
5. Carácter de parada
6. Zona en blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, lo más posible es que los datos codificados que leas sean de una longitud fija, por lo tanto, puedes aprovechar esa característica, en el evento `TextChanged`, puedes verificar la longitud y así en los dos casos funcionaría (sea leido o ingresado por una persona). [Aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) te queda información sobre este evento

```
    private void textBoxConsulta_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBoxConsulta.Text.Length == 10)
        {
            //hacer consulta
        }
    }
```

Ahora bien, sí la longitud es cambiante, puedes usar el mismo evento del lector de código de barras para hacer la consulta (además de meter el texto en el `TextBox`, también haces la consulta) y para las personas, puedes agregar una tecla especial que cuando le den click se haga la consulta, por medio del evento `KeyPress`. [Aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx) te dejo información sobre este evento

```
    private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            //hacer consulta
        }
    }
```

Ahí haces la consulta cuando la persona precione la tecla `Enter` y así te evitas el botón para hacer la consulta. [Aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) te dejo la información sobre las teclas que puedes comparar en C#

También puedes ejecutar la consulta sí se preciona una secuencia de teclas, esto lo logras con el evento `KeyUp`, aquí te dejo un ejemplo que se ejecutaría al teclear la combinación Ctrl+F

```
    private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyData) == Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control) + Convert.ToInt32(Keys.F))
        {
            //hacer consulta
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Fácilmente el textbox tiene un evento TextBox.`TextChanged`, al que puedes suscribirte y de ahi obtener automáticmanete lo que se va llenando en el cuadro.

Ten cuidado, porque se va a ejecutar por cada carácter que se ingrese, con lo cual deberias esperar a que el número este completo para hacer el query.

Una duda que me queda con tu pregunta, es como haces el escaneo, pq también podrías disparar la búsqueda una vez finalizado el escaneo.

Edicion por los comentarios:

Si el codigo es fijo, puedes contar la cantidad de caracteres y no ejecutar el metodo de busqueda hasta que llegues a la cantidad necesaria.

Comment: como hago para que se ejecute cuando tenga el codigo que necesito

Comment: Me imagino que el sdk de tu dispositivo (Scanner) tiene un evento que espera a ser lanzado cuando este completo, ademas con la respuesta de @gbianchi podras solucionar tu problema

Comment: Cual respuesta?

Comment: @gbianchi, el escaneo lo hago con lector de barras, todos los codigos de barras son de tipo code-128, pero tambien puede ser diguitado, no presisamente escaneado

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que haga el query cuando yo termine de diguitar o escanear??

Comment: @use2105 cuenta la cantidad de caracteres.

Comment: Hola, Cuando el lector te escribe los datos en el textbox (los escribe todos de golpe) suele enviar un cr lf al final del mismo con lo que podrías capturar el evento TextChanged del textbox en cuestión como ya te han indicado y realizar una búsqueda en bbdd y mostrar los resultados en pantalla...